# Нужны ли запятые в моем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в предложении:

**А теперь если хотите помочь - уходите**?

Answer (score 2):

**Возможны два варианта:**

(1) А тепЕрь, если хотите помОчь,  уходите. (2) А теперь если хотИте помочь ― уходите. Интонация разная.

В большинстве случаев запятые ставятся, но вариант без запятых также встречается. В этом случае союз А и наречие относятся к подчинительному союзу.

[Розенталь. § 33. Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

Примеры:

(1) **А теперь, если** вы не возражаете, давайте пробираться к выходу.

**А теперь, если** вы не раздумали, пойдем к нему наверх и скажем о нашем решении соединиться законным браком. [А. И. Куприн. Жанета (1933)]

(2) Отделение открывалось как игрушка Пахомовой, она ею побаловалась, **а теперь если** вЫ хотите ― играйте.

Мне и прежде делали блистательные предложения, но я их не принимал; **а теперь если** приму, **то** меня едва ли кто обвинит. [А. Н. Островский. Письма (1853)]

Я не посылал письма к Лидерсу по причине, которую уже объяснял вам, **а теперь если** пошлю его по почте, **так** ему и некогда будет прочесть его, и читать он не станет. [И. С. Аксаков. Письма родным (1849-1856)

Отметим, что в приведенных примерах при отсутствии запятых союз двойной: ЕСЛИ...ТО, ЕСЛИ....ТАК. При пропуске второй части союза ставится тире.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в тех предложениях, где отсутствует запятая поле "теперь", 
можно без проблем пренести "теперь" в другое место в придаточном предложении, 
что доказывает его принадлежность именно придаточному:
"А теперь если приму, то меня едва ли кто обвинит" -> "А если приму теперь, то меня едва ли кто обвинит".
В отличие от этого, при наличии запятой "теперь" принадлежит главному предложению, и это можно доказать, переместив его в другое место в главном: "А теперь, если хотите помочь, - уходите." -> "А теперь уходите, если хотите помочь" 
Прав ли я в этих рассуждениях?

Comment: Перестановка придаточного - это формальный прием, если перестановку нельзя сделать, то запятая не ставится. Но если можно сделать, то возможен авторский выбор. Например: В частности когда началась экспериментальная проверка действия станка, пришлось проводить дополнительную исследовательскую работу.  В этом предложении скорее всего два решения.